# Incorrect value of ta.lowest(12) pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I need to know the lowest price for 12 bars so i use ta.lowest(12) but i got incorrect value. My code:

```
order_price = ta.lowest(12)
lbl = label.new(bar_index, na)
label.set_text( lbl, "order="+str.tostring(order_price))
label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
label.set_yloc( lbl, yloc.belowbar)
label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```

and how it looks on chart: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using this inside an `if` statement. Something like this:

```
if myCondition
    order_price = ta.lowest(12)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, na)
    label.set_text( lbl, "order="+str.tostring(order_price))
    label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
    label.set_yloc( lbl, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```

In that case, you'll probably have seen this warning:

```
The function 'ta.lowest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
```

You should call `ta.lowest(12)` in the main code so that it can execute on every bar. If not, you're only calling it when your `if` statement is true, and so it'll only check the low of the bars on which you called it.

You could mitigate by something like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

myLowest = ta.lowest(12)  // Call the function on every bar, in the main program

if myCondition
    order_price = myLowest  // Use the value in your if statement
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, na)
    label.set_text( lbl, "order="+str.tostring(order_price))
    label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
    label.set_yloc( lbl, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```